# Можно ли объявить "врЕменную" переменную в классе?

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть класс включающий несколько методов и несколько свойств. Есть метод generate и метод calculate. В первом заполняется массив чисел Map, во втором производятся манипуляции с этим массивом и результат заносится в одно из свойств класса. Возможно ли каким-то образом определить Map, чтобы он был временным и не занимал память после вызова метода Calculate?

Comment: объявить Map полем класса и после calculate заnullить?

Comment: `public void Calculate() {... Map = null;}`

Comment: Как насчет передачи Map в параметре? Тогда поле в классе не нужно и специально ничего предпринимать не придется для освобождения памяти.

Comment: Зануление помогло, спасибо. Насчет передачи параметром - тоже думал, но занулением оказалось проще - всего одна строчка

Comment: @АлексейМайборода, при таком занулении есть шанс, что где-то будет попутка использовать это поле(?) и получить `NullReferenceException`. Добавь маленький пример, чтобы было понятно что как и где сейчас вызывается

Comment: @АлексейМайборода: Передача массива как параметра — правильный путь. Иначе вы можете случайно запустить два раза одновременно метод `Generate`, и один из результатов затрёт другой. Используйте поля класса по назначению — для хранения состояния класса. Для передачи параметров используйте параметры.